# how to save CoreDocument in Stanford nlp to disk 2

Tags: stanford-nlp

Followed Professor Manning's suggestion to use the ProtobufAnnotationSerializer and did something wrong.

used serializer.writeCoreDocument on the correctly working document; Later read written file with pair = serializer.read; then used pair.second InputStream p2 = pair.second; p2 was empty resulting in a null pointer when running Pair pair3 = serializer.read(p2);

```
public void writeDoc(CoreDocument document, String filename ) {
    AnnotationSerializer serializer = new 
ProtobufAnnotationSerializer();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try { 
        OutputStream ks = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        ks = serializer.writeCoreDocument(document, ks);
        ks.flush();
        ks.close();
    }catch(IOException ioex) {
        logger.error("IOException "+ioex);
    }
  }

public void ReadSavedDoc(String filename) {
    // Read
    byte[]kb = null;
    try {
        File initialFile = new File(filename);
        InputStream ks = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        ProtobufAnnotationSerializer serializer = new 
ProtobufAnnotationSerializer();
        InputStream kis = new 
ByteArrayInputStream(ks.readAllBytes());
        ks.close();
        Pair<Annotation, InputStream> pair = serializer.read(kis);
        InputStream p2 = pair.second;
        int nump2 = p2.available();
        logger.info(nump2);
        byte[] ba = p2.readAllBytes();
        Annotation readAnnotation = pair.first;
        Pair<Annotation, InputStream> pair3 = serializer.read(p2);
        kis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception: "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Professor Manning -tried your suggestion but did something wrong.  Posted full attempt as how to save CoreDocument in Stanford nlp to disk 2 - Don

Answer (score 0):

This line is unnecessary and should be deleted:

```
Pair<Annotation, InputStream> pair3 = serializer.read(p2);
```

If you have set up `readAnnotation` correctly that's the end of the read/write process.  `p2` is empty because you have read all its contents already.

There is a clear example of how to use serialization here:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/itest/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ProtobufSerializationSanityITest.java

You will have to also build a `CoreDocument` from an `Annotation`.

```
CoreDocument readDocument = new CoreDocument(readAnnotation);
```